# Adding tracing feature for async-graphql throws Cargo error

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, async-graphql

I tried to add the `tracing` extension for `async-graphql` today adding the `tracing` feature in `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
async-graphql = { version = "6.0.11", default-features = false, features = [
  "tracing",
] }
```

but I'm having this error (never seen before):

```
error: failed to select a version for `futures-executor`.
    ... required by package `futures v0.3.29`
    ... which satisfies dependency `futures = "^0.3.28"` (locked to 0.3.29) of package `cmd v0.1.0 (C:\prj\src\cmd)`
versions that meet the requirements `^0.3.29` are: 0.3.29

all possible versions conflict with previously selected packages.

  previously selected package `futures-executor v0.3.28`
    ... which satisfies dependency `futures-executor = "^0.3"` (locked to 0.3.28) of package `opentelemetry_sdk v0.21.1`
    ... which satisfies dependency `opentelemetry_sdk = "^0.21"` (locked to 0.21.1) of package `worker v0.1.0 (C:\prj\src\worker)`
    ... which satisfies path dependency `worker` (locked to 0.1.0) of package `cmd v0.1.0 (C:\prj\src\cmd)`

failed to select a version for `futures-executor` which could resolve this conflict
```

All my dependencies are up to date.

Why?

Comment: Weird, can you try running `cargo update -p futures-executor@0.3.28 --precise 0.3.29`? Maybe after removing the "tracing" feature and putting it back after.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with `cargo clean`.

Stackoverflow asks me to add more text to this answer.

Rust is good!